# Is my input being written properly to my array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buffer[100]= {};
int length = 0;

cout << "Enter a string: ";

do
{
    cin >> buffer;
}
while(cin.eof());

length = strlen(buffer);
int squareNum = ceil(sqrt(length));

cout << squareNum;
cout << buffer;

}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is fill a character array with the string I enter. However I believe it's only writing to the array until a space appears.

```
Ex. 
Input: this is a test
Output: this

Input:thisisatest
Output:thisisatest
```

Why is it stopping at the spaces? I'm pretty sure it has to the with the .eof loop

Answer (score 1):

```
while(cin.eof());
```

It's not likely you are at eof() after reading one word.  You want

```
while(! cin.eof());
```

or more properly a loop something like

```
while(cin >> buffer);
```

Or, even better, dispense with the char arrays and use a `string` and `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::getline()` to get every line e.g

`std::getline (std::cin,name)`

By doing that your input will not be separated by white space delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cin.eof()`, why don't you try something like:

```
std::string a;

while (std::getline(std::cin, a))
{
    //...
}
```